# rails I18n thinking-sphinx how can define index

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, translation, thinking-sphinx

I have two problems.I am using rails 3.2 and thinking-sphinx and also my application is translateable.I am using I18n for this purpose.So you know i have a table users.They have occupations and the occupations are translateable.I am defining index like the following.

```
define_index do
  indexes occupation, 
  indexes name, 
  .....
  ......
  has is_active    
  set_property :enable_star => 1
  set_property :min_infix_len => 3
 end
```

Now i am not sure about how to index the translations of occupations.Secondly i want to priotise my search so that it gives more priority to the occupation than name.
Thanks to you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index translations with `translations.field_name` .In your case you have to do `translations.occupation` to add it in the search index.For the second need you have to set the field weights. Follow this edited code :

```
  define_index do
  indexes translations.occupation, :as => :occupation
  indexes name, :as => :name
  .....
  ......
  has is_active    
  set_property :enable_star => 1
  set_property :min_infix_len => 3
  set_property :field_weights => {
    :occupation => 2,
    :name => 1,        
}
end
```